# Why is my nested form not showing up at all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

This is what I have:

post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replies, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

reply.rb:

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

posts/_reply_fields.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :content, "Reply" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %><br />
</p>
```

posts/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :user %>
  </div>
  <div class="replies">
    <% f.fields_for :replies do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'reply_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

schema.rb:

```
  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.string   "user"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "replies", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "post_id"
  end
```

The **output** in the replies parts is just:

```
<div class="replies">
  </div>
```

The **reply fields** are not showing up at all. What could be the problem?

Comment: I think you may have missed an equal sign: `<%= f.fields_for...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <div class="replies">
    <%= f.fields_for :replies do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'reply_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to the comment & answer, you also need to `build` the `replies` ActiveRecord objects:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.replies.build 
end
```

Comment: Thanks but strange, a new reply is added each time I edit a post. Even if the edit action in the reply controller is empty.

Comment: Are you using inherited resources or something similar?

Comment: @Rick Peck in routes.rb? No, they are just listed one after another.

Comment: You commented that your form shows up when you edit a post although you don't have any code in the edit action -- I was wondering if that was because you're using `inherited_resources` (which would negate the need for code in the edit cation)?

Comment: Well, no, don't have anything that says `inherited_resources` in my code.

Comment: What about in your GemFile?

Comment: Nope, nothing, this is very strange.

Comment: hmmmmm - do you have any links we could check out? R

Comment: Sory, no. Thanks anyway. I may post a new question about this.

Comment: No problem! Go on - post a new Q!